# How to Concatenate Multiple Textviews Which are One Word Just Like All TextViews (Words) are Merged as Paragraph

Tags: java, android, textview, paragraph, clickable

I have multiple textviews. And all textviews are one word. I want to build a paragraph by using them. But they should not lose their textview feature. So they should not be used as string. Because then, I want them to be clickable one by one.

Comment: You can put them in a flexbox list https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: Yeah @ChristilynArjona, it is well done with flex box. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single textview and spannable string to make the words clickable separately.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I cant differentiate spannable string ID's. Just like my example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60930415/could-we-define-unknown-amount-of-clickable-texts-which-have-different-outputs-i

Answer (score 0):

```
      TextView textview1,textview2,textview3;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    textview1 = findViewById(R.id.textview1);

    textview2 = findViewById(R.id.textview2);

    textview3 = findViewById(R.id.textview3);

    textview1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           //

        }
    });




   textview2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           //

        }
    });


     textview3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           //

        }
    });



 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I want whole words have different ID to click. And when I click on words, I want them all (all words) do different thing(ex: they show which word they are)

Comment: Okay, my answer is an example of what you should do, you need to treat every single word as a separated textview

Comment: Thanks for your return. But I dont know their numbers, so I should make textview programmatically in for-loop. And the main problem is how I can concatenate them like paragraph. Now, I try flex box.

Comment: So you need to do a recyclerview and adapter

Comment: May they help me for it?

Comment: Sure, it's designed for issues like that

Comment: Flex Box helped me to achieve. But your ways are in my mind. I will try both of them. Thank you.